# Importance of column regular matrices and its relation to the error-correcting codes.

Tags: matrices, coding-theory, reed-muller-codes

I have been working with BCH codes to construct compressed sensing matrices. So, first I give a brief introduction to BCH codes.

In coding theory, the Bose–Chaudhuri–Hocquenghem codes
(BCH codes) are a class of cyclic error-correcting codes
that are constructed using polynomials over a finite field
(also called the Galois field).
The BCH codes have length $2^{\bar{m}}-1$, where $\bar{m}$ is
a positive integer. In this work, for an odd
integer $d$,
a $d$-BCH code represents a binary BCH code of length
$2^{\bar{m}}-1$ which has $\alpha^1,\ \alpha^2,...,\alpha^{d-1}$
but not $\alpha^{d}$ as roots of its generating polynomial,
where $\alpha$ is a primitive element of $GF(2^{\bar{m}})$.
For an even integer $d$, a $d$-BCH code is a code consisting of the
code vectors of even weight in a $(d-1)$-BCH code.
The weight of a code vector is defined as the number
of non-zero elements in it.
For a binary linear code $\mathcal{C}$,
the symbol $a_j$ represents the number of code vectors of weight $j$ in
$\mathcal{C}$.

Now, I come to the main topic.
Just for example, I am taking a $2016$-BCH code, where $\bar{m} = 12$.  We will denote this code by $\mathcal{C}$. Now, according to the work of  T. Kasami, this BCH code has the following weight distribution:

\begin{equation}
 a_{2016} = 131040
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 a_{2048} = 4095
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 a_{2080} = 127008
\end{equation}

Now, define a matrix $A\in\{0,1\}^{4095\times 131040}$, which consists of all the code vectors of weight $2016$ in $\mathcal{C}$. Notice that $A$ is a column regular matrix because every column has weight $2016$. In my research work, I have been searching for **rectangular** ( where the number of rows is less than the number of columns ) column regular matrices. And I believe that in error-correcting codes I will find many useful rectangular column regular matrices.

Now, we will examine the value of the inner product between two distinct columns of $A$. Let $a,\ b$ be the two distinct arbitrary columns of the matrix $A$. Since $a,\ b$ are two valid code vectors, their modular sum would also be a valid code vector. This means,

\begin{equation}
(a+b)mod\ 2 = c,\ \mbox{for some}\ c\in\mathcal{C}.\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
\end{equation}

Now, let $wt(v)$ denote the weight of a code vector $v\in\mathcal{C}$. Then the equation $(1)$ leads to
\begin{equation}
wt((a+b)mod\ 2) = wt(c).\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
\end{equation}

It is not difficult to see that
\begin{equation}
wt((a+b)mod\ 2) = wt(a) + wt(b) - 2 \langle a , b \rangle , \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)
\end{equation}
where $\langle a , b \rangle$ denotes the inner product of $a,\ b$.

On substituting equation $(3)$ in equation $(2)$ and rearranging , we get
\begin{equation}
\langle a , b \rangle = \frac{wt(a) + wt(b) - wt(c)}{2}.\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (4)
\end{equation}
Since, $wt(a) = wt(b) = 2016$, and $wt(c)= 2016,\ 2048,\ 2080$, on substituting these values in equation $(4)$, we get the following possible values of $\langle a , b \rangle$:
\begin{equation}
\langle a , b \rangle = 1008,\ 992,\ 976 .
\end{equation}

You can see that $\langle a, b \rangle = 992\pm 16$. However, this $\pm 16$ interval is not working quite well for me. It would have been better for me if we had $\langle a , b \rangle = 992\pm 8$.

**So, I am looking for your expert opinions. Do you know any error-correcting codes in which the inner product between any two distinct code vectors of the matrix $A$ lies in a small interval like $\alpha \pm \delta$, where $\delta$ is as small as possible?**

Comment: Wasn't this possibility ruled out in earlier questions you asked? In any case, it is highly unlikely; I do acknowledge that there may not have been an actual disproof of your goal.

Comment: @kodlu ; It is not like my previous question. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: I am usually bad with arithmetic but, are your computations  in (4) correct? If a,b,c are all of weight 2016, then <a,b>=2016/2=1008. If c has weight 2048 then <a,b>=992; if c has weight 2080 then <a,b>=976.

Comment: @kodlu ; Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

The Welch bound can be used to lower bound the maximum inner product of codewords, given other code parameters. See wikipedia, as well as my answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261812/vectors-that-are-almost-orthogonal-on-average-lower-bounds-on-dimension/261821#261821). The bound is most powerful if you express the codewords as vectors in the alphabet $\{\pm 1\}$ instead of $\{0,1\}$ and use the usual inner product on real vectors. So a codeword $(0100)$ becomes $(1,-1,1,1).$ Observe that if the Hamming distance between $a,b$ is $d,$ then the inner product $<a,b>=n-2d$.

Let $e\geq 1$ be an integer and let $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ be distinct vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n.$ Then the following inequalities hold
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m \left| \langle a_i, a_j \rangle \right|^{2e} \geq \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^m \langle a_i,a_i\rangle^e \right)^2}{\binom{n+e-1}{e}}.
$$

I have had a quick look for the parameters of what you are hoping to achieve. *Please check my computations.* I take $e=1,$ $m=131040,$ $n=4095.$ The Hamming weights of the constant weight code you have satisfy
$w\in\{2016,2048,2080\}$ which translates into the inner products lying in the set $\{-1,-1+64,-1-64\}=\{-1,63,-65\}.$ This implies the maximum magnitude of the inner product is $\theta_{max}=65.$

I claim that this cannot be improved. Applying the Welch bound gives
$$
\sum_{1\leq i\neq j\leq m} \langle a_i,a_j \rangle^2+m n^2 \geq 
\frac{\left( \sum_{i=1}^m \langle a_i,a_i \rangle\right)^2}{n}=
\frac{m^2 n^2}{n}=m^2n,
$$
which then gives
$$
m(m-1) \theta_{max}^2 \geq m^2 n- m n^2
$$
and if I plug in the values for $m,n$ I obtain the lower bound
$$
\theta_{max}^2 \geq 3967.06,
$$
or $\theta_{max}^2 \geq 62.99.$ This means that the *weight* of the modulo 2 sum of any two distinct zero-one codewords (call them $c_i$ not to confuse with $a_i$) is bounded by
$$
|n-2 w(c_i,c_j) |=|4095-2 w(c_i,c_j)|\geq 62.99,
$$
which implies the weight is at least 31.5 or so away from 4095/2=2047.5. I believe that this means under your definition of $<a,b>$ you cannot do better than about $15.75$ away from 992.

Comment: I appreciate that you tried to prove it for me. But while proving this, why did you assume $m = 131040$? I need $m = 20,000$ only. Therefore, I believe that there might exist an error-correcting code, where I would get $\langle a,\ b\rangle = 992 \pm 10$ .

Comment: Your mathematical skill gives me the impression that you are an eminent scientist. If it is true, I would consider it as my luck that I got the opportunity to interact with you.

Comment: I missed where you stated $m=20,000$ in the original question. So, you will be happy to find a subset of 20,000 words out of the 131,040? Plug in $m=20,000$ to what I did and see if the Welch bound rules this out.